# Cannot send authorization bearer token throught axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, get, bearer-token

When I check in postman and sent the request to an api endpoint with the token works good:

[image]

But when I make the same request in expressjs to the api  it sent me an unauthorized response:

Request:

```
try {
const response1 = await axios.get(`https://url/payment/pse/banks`,{headers: { 
'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`    

   
  }})
  console.log("lista",response1.data);
  } catch (error) {
 console.log(error.response.data)
   }
```

Response:

```
 {
  success: false,
  titleResponse: 'Unauthorized.',
  textResponse: 'Unauthorized.',
  lastAction: '',
  data: { token: '' }
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the response there is `token: ''`, so this suggests that the Bearer token is empty

Comment: Also, I don't think `Content-Type` and `Authorization` should be between quotes